# Android Studio -- linking with a .aar that contains a .so

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, aar

I'm migrating an existing, working project from Eclipse to Android Studio.  The code base consists of a native C++ library built with the NDK (libMylib.so), a Java class that wraps all the native code (MyClass.java), and a test harness(MyApp).

In Android Studio, I've created a stand-alone project (not just a module) that builds "MyClass", and that project has a "src/main/jniLibs" folder where I place "libMyLibrary.so".

The project builds and produces "MyClass.aar", which contains all of its dependencies -- including those .so files.

My test app imports this .aar file as a new dependency "module".  It builds and deploys to a device, but encounters a runtime exception when trying to call a native method contained in the .so file.

```
Trying to load lib /data/data/com.mycompany.webview/lib/libMylib.so 0x4131cd18
Added shared lib /data/data/com.mycompany.webview/lib/libMylib.so 0x4131cd18
nativeCalls.cpp﹕ JNI_OnLoad() called successfully.
No implementation found for native Lcom/mycompany/Mylib/MyClass;.nativeInit
Shutting down VM
```

The debug statement printed in "JNI_OnLoad()" is mine, so I know the correct .so is being loaded without issue. But then something goes wrong with the call to 'nativeInit()'.

What sorts of things could cause this kind of failure?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you building **libMylib.so** with `ndk-build` or you rely on the Gradle NDK support? In the latter case, post your `build.gradle`. In any case, add some more output to your log in `JNI_OnLoad()` to make sure that this is not some old version of your library that is loaded.

Comment: The native code is built on command line with ndk-build.  Then the .so file is copied to the appropriate directory (jniLibs) of MyLibrary.  It's the same version of my library that I'm currently using in product and that builds correctly using Eclipse.  No  code changes.

Comment: NDK comes with a nice `nm` command (you can find it somewhere in `prebuilt/…/bin` directory for the toolchain you are using). Run this `nm -D` on **libMylib.so** that you manually extract from the APK, to understand if really implementation of **MyClass.nativeInit()** method is missing somehow.

Comment: Cool thanks for pointing out that tool.  See my comment below what I found out the hard way.  This tool probably would've made it obvious sooner.

Answer (score 0):

1) What value does *JNI_OnLoad()* return? In the code that I have it is `JNI_VERSION_1_6`.

2) Are the function names correct?

```
cd bin/classes
javah com.example.MyClass com.example.OneMoreClass
```

This will generate the correct C/C++ headers for your native functions.

Comment: There are no source code changes.  I've simply taken the existing MyLibrary.so and MyClass.java and  put them into Android Studio.  So no  method signature changes or anything like that.  I will try adding more debug statements around  JNI_OnLoad() but it doesn't do much besides set the global JVM variable.

Comment: Found the problem.  Stupid rookie mistake -- Android Studio changed the casing on the package name somewhere along the line and I needed to manually make the native calls match.  Poof!